# Illegal chracter exception while using JavascriptExecutor in selenium webdriver

Tags: javascript, selenium

I am using Selenium webdriver(2.37.0) to automate one web form. Using JavascriptExecutor to set certain value in select option , as below:

```
if (driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor)
 {

    js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
 }

    js.executeScript("document.getElementById('ddlRegCategory').value = 'XYZ';​​​​​​​​​​");
```

I am getting illegal character exception on above script line.

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: illegal character

Command duration or timeout: 25 milliseconds
Build info: version: '2.37.0', revision: 'a7c61cb', time: '2013-10-18 17:14:00'
System info: host: 'mitalee-PC', ip: '169.254.147.196', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0'
Session ID: b98a4393-d1eb-4f21-93bd-87248e58228b
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, version=26.0, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=true, nativeEvents=true, webStorageEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:193)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:554)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:463)
    at HRMS.main(HRMS.java:39)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$UnknownServerException: illegal character

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the problem, but what is your question anyway?

Comment: @FelixKling: My doubt is , why I am getting illegal character exception in Java script line.Is that script is not well formatted?

Comment: Can you post the HTML?  Maybe we can figure out why FindElement isn't working, rather than using javascript.

Comment: <select id="ddlRegCategory" class="formfield" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ddlRegCategory\',\'\')', 0)" name="ddlRegCategory">
<option value="" selected="selected">-- Select --</option>           
<option value="C0018 ">Option1</option>
<option value="C0002 ">Option2</option>
</select>

Comment: @user1177636 : Above is the exception I am getting. Previous question "is not working" because on particular form page , selenium not detecting the element and I can't see any values sent to element via  driver.findElement(By.id("txtReason")).sendKeys("reason");

Comment: @Mitaleek: Which browser your using? And can you remove your semicolon from the js code and give it a try?

Comment: @Ant's: I am n more getting illegal character exception , since it was problem with Eclipse editor's encoding. I resolved it. However , Now I am getting (...)is null for ElementID. I am applying a null verification before actually putting value in it.